# Why we can neglect high-order term $x^2$ in expression $x+x^2$ as $x$ approaches zero?

Tags: calculus

I read this: http://www.bndhep.net/Lab/Math/Calculus.html#The%20Infinitesimal%20Limit

> Consider the expression $x + x^2$. How does its value vary as $x$ gets
> smaller?
>
> As $x$ gets smaller, the expression $x + x^2$ gets closer to $x$. The
> $x^2$ part becomes insignificant. At some point, $x + x^2$ becomes
> indistinguishable from $x$. We may not agree about when we can first
> ignore the $x^2$ part, but as we keep making $x$ smaller, we will
> eventually all be forced to agree that there is no significance
> difference between $x$ and $x + x^2$.
>
> The fact that $x^2$ becomes insignificant compared to $x$ for very
> small values of $x$ is a fundamental principle of infinitesimal
> calculus. We say $x$ is infinitesimal when we allow its value to
> approach zero, but never actually reach zero, and we write $x$
> approaches $0$. To express the behavior of $x + x^2$ as $x$ approaches 0
> we say, "The limit of $x + x^2$ as x approaches $0$ is $x$."

I didn't fully understand why $x^2$ was neglected in expression $x+x^2$.
I assumed that $x$ was very small and so $x^2$ became zero.

Is it right?

Thanks!

Comment: In my opinion, that section of the web page is extremely poorly written and is more likely to lead to false impressions than mathematical insight. I recommend that you switch to another source for your learning.

Comment: Visualize the situation with explicit numerical examples.  If $~\displaystyle x = \frac{1}{1000},~$ then $~\displaystyle x^2 = \frac{1}{1000000}.~$  Then, you have that although $~\displaystyle \frac{1}{1000}~$ is small, $~\displaystyle \frac{1}{1000000}~$ is much smaller.

Comment: The main reason is not that $x^2\to 0$, but the fact that $\frac{x^2}{x} \to 0$